# In selenium, how to click all elements in long list of lazy loaded elements?

Tags: selenium, dynamic, lazy-loading

**What do I have** - I'm automating one website where there is a big list of elements but not loaded all at once. Say for example I have 200 elements in the list, but only 10 elements are loaded at the moment, and out of these 10 only 5 are visible on the screen.

**What I want to do** - Now I want to select all of these elements 1 by 1, by clicking on them, because clicking on element selects check box in front of each (Basically i want to tick checkbox). So i will 1st select 5 elements which are visible on page, then i will scroll down to select another visible group, like wise i want to select all 200 elements.

**What Problem I'm facing** - webdriver.findElements(..) method is returning list of 10 elements which are loaded. But it is not returning list in the order in which the elements are displayed on the page. I'm using for loop to iterate over the list and clicking on elements one by one.

As a result if 6th element is clicked which is not displayed in page, page scrolls till that element and click it, now after that if 2nd element got chance to be clicked, then page should scrolls up to click it, but this time since DOM has loaded again due to scrolling, I get StaleElementReferenceException. If I handle this exception within try catch and get element list again by finding elements, it is not guaranteed to be in the correct order and does not solve my problem.

**Solution??** - Is there any way in selenium to get list of elements in order it is displayed on page? Or please let me know what should be the approach to achieve above scenario?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Note - JAVA is being used as a programming laungage.

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_, your _code trials_ and error stack trace (if any)

Answer (score 0):

If you also post the HTML that would be more helpful to explain the solution. I am trying to give you a solution by making some assumptions.
Taking a sample HTML code

```
<div id "checkbox_container>
     <input type="checkbox " id="checkbox1 ">
     <input type="checkbox " id="checkbox1 ">
     <input type="checkbox " id="checkbox1 ">
     <input type="checkbox " id="checkbox1 ">
     .
     .
     .
     <input type="checkbox " id="checkbox1 ">
 </div>
```

Now write the locators that will give the `count` of the available checkbox elements and a locator that will select the specific checkbox.

```
public class SamplePageObjects {
        //This locator will select all available checkboxes
        public static By ALL_CHECK_BOX = By.xpath("//div[@id='checkbox_container']//input");

        //This locator will select the particular element for the given index
        public static getMeExpectedCheckBox(int index, int maxCount) {
            if (index < 0 || index > maxCount) {
                throw new IlleagalArgumentException(index+" is not a valid index");
            }
            return By.xpath("//div[@id='checkbox_container']//input[" + index + "];
        }
    }
```

Now, write your page class

```
public class SamplePage{

    //Gives the count of available elements
    public int getCountOfAvailableCheckBox(WebDriver driver){
        return driver.findElements(SamplePageObjects.ALL_CHECK_BOX).size();
    }

    //Selects the specific element
    public void selectWebElement(WebDriver driver,int index){
        driver.findElement(SamplePageObjects.getMeExpectedCheckBox(index).click();
    }

    //Selects all available element one by one
    public void click(){
        int totalCount = getCountOfAvailableCheckBox();
        for(int i=0; i< totalCount-1; i++){
            try{
                selectWebElement(i,totalCount);
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
                selectWebElement(i,totalCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

So first get the list of all available checkboxes. After getting the count, just pass the index value to the locator and perform the action.

Hope it will help you.